# makefile : no such file or directory to create my elf

Tags: c, makefile, embedded

I am using a simple makefile for my build environment where this is my base makefile and it will in turn call the other makefiles.

here while linking i am getting a error like

```
ddump: warning Can't open file D:/DAS_Work_In_Progress/DAS_Folder_Structure/Autosar_build/Application/Mcu/Build/out/Test_MCU.elf: No such file or directory
ddump: warning 
D:/DAS_Work_In_Progress/DAS_Folder_Structure/Autosar_build/Application/Mcu/Build/out/Test_MCU.elf : Unrecognized file type.  Neither COFF nor ELF
```

Here is my simple makefile:

```
################################################################################
# Makefile to compile and build the Test application with the AUTOSAR MCU      #
# Driver Component (For Test purposes only)                                    #
################################################################################


LD:=C:/WindRiver/diab/5.9.3.0/WIN32/bin/dld.exe

# Current application name
CURRENT_APPL = Test_MCU

# Get the current working directory into variable "PROJECT_ROOT"
export PROJECT_ROOT:=$(CURDIR)

# Get current configuration path
GENDATA_DIR = $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Bsw/Gendata

# Get current source code path
SSC_ROOT = $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Bsw/MICROSAR/Bsw

# Get current Test application path
APP_ROOT = $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Application

TARGET = -tPPCE200Z0HVES:simple


OBJ_PATH:=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/Application/Mcu/Build/obj
OUTPUT =  $(APP_ROOT)/Mcu/Build/out/$(CURRENT_APPL)
LINKER_FILE = $(APP_ROOT)/Mcu/MPC5646C.dld

################################################################################
# Modules to be included in the project                                        #
################################################################################
INCLUDE_FILES+=-I C:/WindRiver/diab/5.9.3.0/include


GENERATED_SOURCE_FILES =

CC_FILES_TO_BUILD =
CPP_FILES_TO_BUILD =

CC_INCLUDE_PATH =
CPP_INCLUDE_PATH =

################################################################################
# Reference to Test_App make file                                              #
################################################################################
INCLUDE_FILES+=-I $(APP_ROOT)/MCU/mak/$(CURRENT_APPL)_defs.mak
INCLUDE_FILES+=-I $(APP_ROOT)/MCU/mak/$(CURRENT_APPL)_rules.mak

################################################################################
# Reference to Gendata make file                                               #
################################################################################
INCLUDE_FILES+=-I $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Bsw/mak/Mcu/$(CURRENT_APPL)_Config_defs.mak
INCLUDE_FILES+=-I $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Bsw/mak/Mcu/$(CURRENT_APPL)_Config_rules.mak

################################################################################
# Reference to Source code make file                                           #
################################################################################
INCLUDE_FILES+=-I $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Bsw/mak/Mcu/$(CURRENT_APPL)_src_defs.mak
INCLUDE_FILES+=-I $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Bsw/mak/Mcu/$(CURRENT_APPL)_src_rules.mak

################################################################################
# Reference to MCAL make file                                                  #
################################################################################
INCLUDE_FILES+=-I $(APP_ROOT)/MCAL/mak/$(CURRENT_APPL)_main_defs.mak
INCLUDE_FILES+=-I $(APP_ROOT)/MCAL/mak/$(CURRENT_APPL)_main_rules.mak

################################################################################
# Reference generic include files                                              #
################################################################################
INCLUDE_FILES+=-I $(SSC_ROOT)/_Common

################################################################################
# Include generated source files list to the global "C" file list
#
CC_FILES_TO_BUILD += $(GENERATED_SOURCE_FILES)
################################################################################

################################################################################
# Search path for source and header files (For Make utility)                   #
################################################################################
VPATH=$(CC_INCLUDE_PATH) \
$(OBJ_PATH)

################################################################################
# Create list of object files from source files                                #
################################################################################
OBJECT_FILES_BUILT := $(subst \,/, $(CC_FILES_TO_BUILD))
OBJECT_FILES_BUILT := $(subst :,/, $(OBJECT_FILES_BUILT))
OBJECT_FILES_BUILT := $(notdir $(OBJECT_FILES_BUILT))

################################################################################

################################################################################
# Prefix -I to all include paths (required for compiler)                       #
################################################################################
COMPILER_INCLUDE := $(patsubst %,-I%,$(CC_INCLUDE_PATH))


my_sources:=$(patsubst %specs.c, , $(CC_FILES_TO_BUILD))


CC = dcc.exe
AS = das.exe
LD = dld.exe

CFLAGS = -Wa,-l -c -g

#CFLAGS = $(TARGET) -c -g  -I  $(my_sources) -Xdebug-local-cie $(INCLUDE_FILES)

$(OUTPUT).elf: $(OBJECT_FILES_BUILT) $(LINKER_FILE)
    $(LD) $(TARGET) -o $(OUTPUT).elf $(OBJECT_FILES_BUILT) -lc $(LINKER_FILE) -m6 > $(OUTPUT).map
    ddump  -Rv $(OUTPUT).elf -o $(OUTPUT).srec



%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(TARGET) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_FILES)  $(COMPILER_INCLUDE) -D AUTOSAR_OS_NOT_USED -o $@ $<

%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $(TARGET) -g -o $@ $<

all: $(OUTPUT).elf

clean:
        rm -f *.o $(OUTPUT).* $(shell find '$(CURDIR)' -iname '*.o')
        rm -f $(shell find '$(CURDIR)' -iname '*.lst')



build: clean all
```

Comment: Does it produce the elf file (`D:/DAS_Work_In_Progress/DAS_Folder_Structure/Autosar_build/Application/Mcu/Build/out/Test_MCU.elf`)?

Comment: ya elf should be produced in that path... now it is only creating .map file in the above path but not elf

Comment: All right, then *simplify*. Verify that the `$(OBJECT_FILES_BUILT)` files and `$(LINKER_FILE)` are there, and if they are, try the `dld.exe` command on the command line (without Make) and tell us the result.

Comment: ya my $(OBJECT_FILES_BUILT) will have all my CC_FILES_TO_BUILD which is there in rules and defs .mak file. and the linker file is there. i tried in cmd propt by giving dld.exe it is asking for option D-LD Linker
Usage: dld [options] input-file...
For more help use the -? or --help options.

Comment: There's the answer: your linking command is malfunctioning, it doesn't produce the elf file. Then the `ddump` command fails because it can't find the elf file. You must figure out what arguments/options to give to `dld.exe` so that it will produce the elf file correctly, then modify the command in the `$(OUTPUT).elf` rule accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your response will try the things and let you know the results

Comment: Hi i could able to solve this problem and my compilation is proceeding now, but in middle i got some error like compiler out of sync in my .h file D:/marquardt/eclipse_worspace/Autosar_build/BSW/MICROSAR/BSW/Mcu\\Mcu_LLD.h", line 950: error (dcc:1173): compiler out of sync. Probably missing ';' or '}'
"D:/marquardt/eclipse_worspace/Autosar_build/BSW/MICROSAR/BSW/Mcu\\Mcu_LLD.h", line 950: error (dcc:1056): illegal function definition
"D:/marquardt/eclipse_worspace/Autosar_build/BSW/MICROSAR/BSW/Mcu\\Mcu_LLD.h", line 950: error (dcc:1117): identifier Mcu_XOSC_ISR not an argument